# Get minimum and maximum value in Array [JSP]

Tags: arrays, jsp, minimum

How can I get the minimum and maximum values in an array with JSP? Is this possible?

Comment: try this [link](http://beginnersbook.com/2014/07/java-finding-minimum-and-maximum-values-in-an-array/)

Comment: Where's your code? How does your array look like? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

you can use collections class to search the max and min in an List . So first you need to convert your array to a list;

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
public class Main {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Integer[] numbers = { 23, 33, 10, 1, 2, 9, 5};
      int min = (int) Collections.min(Arrays.asList(numbers));
      int max = (int) Collections.max(Arrays.asList(numbers));

   }
}
```